# How do you explain a disposition property?

Tags: properties

If we know that an individual has some dispositional property like being disposed to bake a cake. How do we go about analyzing that property?

Comment: Please read [SEP, Dispositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dispositions/) and ask something more concrete.

Comment: [Dispositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dispositions/) is the modern approach to the old philosophical issue about ["virtues"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dormitive_virtue): "the sleep-inducing properties of opium stems from its "virtus dormitiva"."

Answer (score 0):

Dispositional properties are properties objects exhibit under various external conditions based on their, non-relational, categorical properties. An example would be the dispositional property of metals to melt under the introduction of a heat source. Their melting point is in turn determined by their categorical/intrinsic properties - internal structure of chemical bonds.